# POSIX Message Queue - "Message too long" on send

Tags: c, posix, message-queue

I've got a client and a server process and I want to pass messages from the client to the server using POSIX message queue.

In my client code:

```
struct mq_attr attrs = {
    .mq_flags = 0,
    .mq_maxmsg = 10,
    .mq_curmsgs = 0,
    .mq_msgsize = 6200,
    };

    mqd_t mq = mq_open(POSIX_Q_NAME, O_CREAT | O_WRONLY, S_IRUSR | S_IWUSR, &attrs);

  if (mq == (mqd_t)-1) {
    perror("mq_open");
  }

  char* request = "Hello world";
  int res = mq_send(mq, request, strlen(request) + 1, 0);
  if (res == -1) {
    perror("mq_send");
  }
```

I am getting a res == -1, which is logging an mq_send error: `Message too long`. I'm struggling to understand how this can be. I'm currently running my client in isolation, so the server has not attempted to open the message queue first (and set the max message length to a diff value).

Comment: The MQ attributes specified via `mq_open` are used only in the event that the queue is created by that call.  If an existing queue is opened instead then its attributes are not modified.

Comment: Does the queue already exist? According to the [documentation](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/mq_open.html), the parameters supplied with `O_CREAT` have no effect if the named queue already exists. You can test this by also supplying `O_EXCL`, which should fail if the queue exists. The idea here is that queue may already exist, but have a maximum message size smaller than what you're trying to send.

Comment: You can call `mq_getattr` to get the attributes of the queue to see if your values were used or if some earlier creation's values are in use.

Comment: Thanks all for replying. This provided me some helpful extra context. I had rebooted my machine for a different reason and after running it again it works. I'm guessing when I had previously ran my server process it hadn't disposed of the queue correctly and it perhaps still existed in memory. Thank you!